# Image upload in window application ? C#.net?

Tags: winforms

In window application, i have one registration form in that one option is to upload the photo of the user. So how can i do this, generally in web application we have File Upload control using this we can save the image in our project, like that i want to save the photo of the user in any drive of my system. can you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Look into the `OpenFileDialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use File Open Dialog Control. You can retrieve the physical path of the file and copy the file to your system specific location.

Sample:

```
string fulllocimage = openFileDialog1.FileName;
File.Copy(fulllocimage, Path.Combine(@"C:\UploadedImage\",Path.GetFileName(fulllocimage));
```